# How to skip some key-value pairs when converting JSON to Excel Worksheet using XLSX in JS

Tags: javascript, json, excel, xlsx, worksheet

I have an array of objects (JSON) in JS and want to convert it to an Excel worksheet. In the JSON data, there are some key-value pairs I do not want convert to Excel, for example Excel should not contain *year* information like below (PLEASE RUN HTML CODE TO SEE EXCEL OUTPUT REQUIRED):

**JSON data:**

```js
[
  {
    car: "Range Rover",
    color: "silver",
    year: "2021"
  },
  
  {
    car: "Benz",
    color: "black",
    year: "2019"
  },
  
  {
    car: "Toyota",
    color: "silver",
    year: "2020"
  }
]
```

**Excel view (Run the snippet):**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>car</th>
        <th>color</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Range Rover</td>
        <td>silver</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Benz</td>
        <td>black</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>silver</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this using **XLSX** in JS?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do here.

1. After parsing your JSON data, you can save it in an xlsx worksheet, change the worksheet's **!ref** property to the desired range, then add that sheet to the xlsx book.

```
let file = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf-8');
let data = JSON.parse(file);

var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
var ws = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(data);

ws['!ref'] = 'A1:B4';
xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet 1');
xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'test1.xlsx');
```

2. Filter out your the properties that you want from your JSON data into a separate array and then add them to the file.

```
let file = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf-8');
let data = JSON.parse(file);

var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();

let dataArray = [];
data.forEach(d => {
  dataArray.push({"car": d.car, "color": d.color});
});

var ws = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(dataArray);
console.log(ws);
xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet 1');
xlsx.writeFile(wb, 'test2.xlsx');
```

Checking the utility functions documentation might be helpful too.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#utility-functions